# OpenGL (LWJGL+SlickUTIL) - How to cut the texture at specific coords

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I have a 512x512 png image. It is loaded into a texture using SlickUtil, but I cannot figure out how to cut a specific quad from the texture to bind to my glQuad.

Its like a sprite sheet, where I could cut specific images from there.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use OpenGL texture coordinates to do so. In old GL that would be:

```
glBegin (GL_QUADS);
  glTexCoord2f (0.0, 0.5); glVertex2f (0, 0);
  glTexCoord2f (0.5, 0.5); glVertex2f (1, 0);
  glTexCoord2f (0.5, 1.0); glVertex2f (1, 1);
  glTexCoord2f (0.0, 1.0); glVertex2f (0, 1);
glEnd ();
```

This will use the upper left quarter of your image.

Comment: The left top edge will slightly wrap into the lower right pixels with those texture coordinates. Textures are like grid ruled paper where the pixels are centered in the cells, but the texture coordinates 0 and 1 map to the bordering rulings.

Comment: Well, it depends on the wrapping mode, for tiled textures you wouldn't choose `WRAP`. Anyway this is part of a more general problem: [filtering and mipmapping on texture atlases](http://www.infinity-universe.com/Infinity/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=65&Itemid=47).